SCF not converging during NEB calculation
During an NEB calculation, the first cycle worked just fine, but my second image would not converge during the second cycle. The total energy and the estimated scf accuracy were converging normally, until they were not.
I`m getting close to 300 iterations and the error went from 0.0005 Ry to 1000 Ry.
I tried resetting the calculation and increasing the number of images, but neither worked.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thank you.
Here`s the input file:
BEGIN
BEGIN_PATH_INPUT
&PATH
  restart_mode      = 'from_scratch'
  string_method     = 'neb',
  nstep_path        = 150,
  ds                = 1.D0,
  opt_scheme        = "broyden",
  num_of_images     = 10,
  CI_scheme         = 'no-CI',
  path_thr          = 0.05D0,
/
END_PATH_INPUT
BEGIN_ENGINE_INPUT
&CONTROL
  prefix         = "Neb1"
  pseudo_dir = "/gpfs/home/s362484/pseudopot"
  outdir= "./"
/
&system
    a                         =  1.06742e+01
    c                         =  4.65880e+01
    degauss                   =  1.00000e-02
    ecutrho                   =  2.25000e+02
    ecutwfc                   =  2.50000e+01
    ibrav                     = 4
    nat                       = 80
    ntyp                      = 5
    occupations               = "smearing"
    smearing                  = "gaussian"
    starting_magnetization(1) =  0.00000e+00
    starting_magnetization(2) =  2.00000e-01
/
&ELECTRONS
    conv_thr         =  1.00000e-05
    electron_maxstep = 1001
    mixing_beta      =  4.00000e-01
/
&IONS
/
K_POINTS {gamma}

ATOMIC_SPECIES
Ru    101.07000  Ru.pbe-spn-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
Pt    195.07800  Pt.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
C      12.01070  C.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
H       1.00794  H.pbe-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
O      15.99940  O.pbe-nl-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
BEGIN_POSITIONS
FIRST_IMAGE
ATOMIC_POSITIONS {angstrom}
Ru     -0.065919   3.032222   8.318543
Pt      3.903615   0.685619   8.378004
Pt      2.606838   3.041582   8.537927
Ru      1.260634   0.740622   8.308912
Ru      2.588588   1.517128   6.150268
...
C       3.302951   4.874075  10.714625
C       3.279659   3.411146  10.657303
C       4.587083   2.751321  10.735804
C       5.812081   3.492028  10.716704
C       5.844872   4.958714  10.625467
C       4.534420   5.631534  10.748425
H       6.682851   5.452335  11.151564
H       6.731492   2.996793  11.068011
H       4.607310   1.714157  11.106642
H       2.450546   2.918378  11.198736
H       2.404316   5.387043  11.092918
C       4.428448   6.985682  11.366943
O       5.633944   7.461575  11.823709
O       3.370590   7.608459  11.536089
H       5.431690   8.357865  12.192737
H       1.322164   5.000000  12.241429
LAST_IMAGE
ATOMIC_POSITIONS {angstrom}
Ru     -0.077355   3.037259   8.346787
Pt      3.902203   0.712489   8.439945
Pt      2.610079   3.045290   8.596285
Ru      1.258104   0.725496   8.341261
Ru      2.526293   1.458082   6.186066
...
C       3.108881   4.576449  11.230801
C       3.192414   3.160385  10.688648
C       4.575933   2.648714  10.704262
C       5.702772   3.530375  10.704618
C       5.561856   4.984420  10.588326
C       4.165588   5.495311  10.599127
H       6.370253   5.526473  11.103695
H       6.648770   3.071659  11.056688
H       4.665625   1.586435  11.030019
H       2.428779   2.509337  11.163505
H       2.119627   5.057803  11.076180
C       3.942680   6.914219  10.960723
O       4.870831   7.478547  11.778207
O       2.895171   7.577683  10.665514
H       4.621185   8.436037  11.855567
H       3.296984   4.530643  12.337758
END_POSITIONS
END_ENGINE_INPUT
END


Have you optimized well the two structures that you are using?

I have, they both look reasonable. I am also using xcrysden to visualise the step-by-step and it looked fine for the first cycle.

Very quick look, is this a metallic slab with adsorbed molecules? if yes change the mixing mode to "local-TF ". decrease conv_thr to 1.0e-8 or less

As you probably know, SCF convergence can sometimes be tricky. You are using electron_maxstep=1000, which I think is unusually large. If you don't see things converging in ~200 iterations, it is already bad. Please check:

if your geometry is reasonable,
your ecutwfc also appears to be small,
try changing diagonalization: cg can be slow but may be more robust,
play with occupations, smearing, mixing parameters.

Good luck

You said in your post that you were able to achieve electronic convergence for the initial band, and that electronic convergence failed for the system after the first ionic step was taken. My suspicion is that while your initial band may be reasonable, the forces computed have pushed your system into a state where two ions have core overlap.
An initial sanity check could be generating an initial band for your system using e.g. ASE, and visualizing the band using e.g. ovito, just to ensure that atoms are not sliding past each-other outside of those you intend to slide past each-other.
As noted in another answer, a secondary cause could be the accuracy settings employed, although as someone who's spent all their time in VASP, I cannot speak on suitable settings for QE.
Given that a potential cause of the problem here is the system being pushed into an unphysical state, another setting to try however could be the default ionic step size, or ds. While this is likely an over-conservative suggestion, I'd recommend rerunning the calculation using ds=0.1D0 or ds=0.5d0 and seeing if you run into the same electronic convergence problems. A smaller step size should give the system a bit more time to recognize and move away from highly-unphysical configurations (aka very small ion-ion distances).
